# get object attributes based upon arrow function

Tags: javascript, object, lodash, arrow-functions

```
// Sample object:
const abc = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B',
  c: 'C'
}

// Sample Arrow function
const xyz = (item) => item.a
```

Assuming object and arrow function are defined separately, how this arrow function can be used to retrieve value from object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `xyz` function with the `abc` object as an argument and you'll get your `abc.a` property back as the return value.

Example:

```
console.log(xyz(abc))
```